# Check if a Postgres array contains a subarray in order

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I need to write a SQL(or a SQL function) to check if a Postgres item contains a slice of the item. I'll just call this item 'Item'. So basically 'Item' looks like this:

[image]

The size of e1 is always the same as e2.

Now here comes 2 arrays, I'll just call them a1 and a2, which looks like this.

'{b,c,d}', '{2,3,4}'.

The values in e2(a2) have to match exact the same index as in e1(a1), so in this example both the 1st and the 4th items in the table will match, but not the 2nd or the 3rd. So if 2 arrays are '{c,d}', '{3,4}', then the 1st, the 3rd and the 4th items will match.

I have no idea how to do this, do I need to use something like generate_series() to generate all possible slice of the item and then check? I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Hi. In future please don't post screenshots of data; instead, use the site's formatting features to display tables etc. This makes it searchable for people later, and helps out readers with vision difficulties. It also helps people help you since they can copy and paste your sample data when testing. Thanks!

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, the `@>` operator won't help here since it doesn't respect order, it's a set operation.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. I won't do that again :)

Comment: Not a problem, just advice for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns an index in the array `arr` of the subarray `sub`, or 0 if `arr` does not contain `sub`:

```
create or replace function index_of_subarray(arr anyarray, sub anyarray)
returns integer language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
    for i in 1 .. cardinality(arr)- cardinality(sub)+ 1 loop
        if arr[i:i+ cardinality(sub)- 1] = sub then
            return i;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return 0;
end $$;
```

Use:

```
with my_table(e1, e2) as (
values
    ('{a,b,c,d}'::text[], '{1,2,3,4}'::int[]),
    ('{b,c,d,a}', '{1,2,3,4}'),
    ('{c,d}', '{3,4}'),
    ('{b,c,d}', '{2,3,4}')
)

select e1, e2
from my_table
where index_of_subarray(e1, '{b,c,d}') > 0 
and index_of_subarray(e1, '{b,c,d}') = index_of_subarray(e2, '{2,3,4}')

    e1     |    e2     
-----------+-----------
 {a,b,c,d} | {1,2,3,4}
 {b,c,d}   | {2,3,4}
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation you may create a string from the array and query it with `regex/like`.

Which sounds like a naive approach turns out to be faster than the `plpgsql` function of the accepted answer. At least in the following situation:

```sql
drop table if exists temp;
create table temp as
  SELECT array[
    chr((floor(random()*26) + 65)::int),
    chr((floor(random()*26) + 65)::int),
    chr((floor(random()*26) + 65)::int),
    chr((floor(random()*26) + 65)::int),
    chr((floor(random()*26) + 65)::int),
    chr((floor(random()*26) + 65)::int)
    ] as a FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000);
```

Query with like

```sql
\timing

select count(*) from temp
where array_to_string(a, '>>') like '%A>>B%';
 count
-------
  7505
(1 row)

Time: 270,404 ms
```

Query with function

```sql
select count(*) from temp
where index_of_subarray (a, array['A', 'B']) != 0;
 count
-------
  7505
(1 row)

Time: 1999,002 ms (00:01,999)
```

The difference in performance becomes even more clearly when you need to match wildcards:

```sql
select count(*) from temp
where array_to_string(a, '>>') like '%A>>B%>>C>>D%';
 count
-------
     7
(1 row)

Time: 173,343 ms
```

With function

```sql
select count(*) from temp
where index_of_subarray (a, array['A', 'B']) != 0
and index_of_subarray (a, array['A', 'B']) < index_of_subarray (a, array['C', 'D']);
 count
-------
     7
(1 row)

Time: 1999,791 ms (00:02,000)
```

I'm astonished of the difference in performance.

Maybe it's because `plpgsql` is so much slower than the native implementation of Regex. Which is most probably very optimized.

Maybe there is something special in the test situation created that leads to the advantage in performance.

Furthermore to make the stringify solution reliable you need to supply a delimiter to `array_to_string` which does not occur in the array elements. There are situations where this may not be feasible.

But apart from that you may consider to make a string from the array and query it with `like/regex`.